# How to set GET parameters with PyCurl?

Tags: python, rest, get, pycurl

I'm trying to make a GET request for a REST api using PycURL.  I am able to successful make a request if I do not pass any parameters.  I am also able to make a POST request by doing the following:

curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, post_data)

I want to make a get request that includes login parameters. If I try to use the line above to pass the parameters, it tries to make a POST instead.  I can't figure out how to set the login parameters and make a GET request.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

Just like a normal URL on the browser, GET parameters are encoded and appended after a `?` to the URL. Using python's [urllib.urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode), you can do:

```
import urllib
import pycurl

url = 'http://www.google.com/search'
params = {'q': 'stackoverflow answers'}

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params))
... # and so on and so forth ...
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, you can add the HTTPGET option.  c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPGET, 1)

Comment: You may need import urllib.parse then urllib.parse.urlencode(params) in python 3

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no pycurl.GETFIELDS option, so you'll have to pass these parameters in the url, like this:

```
http://your_url/some_path?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

where you should replace param1, param2, value1 and value2 with whichever values you have stored in `post_data`.